# Finding a date closest to a user's next birthday JS

Tags: javascript, date

If I have an unsorted array of future Date objects, what would be the best way to pick out the Date closest to the user's next birthday? For example,

```
    const dates = [new Date(2023, 12, 23), 
                   new Date(2023, 12, 2), 
                   new Date(2023, 12, 6), 
                   new Date(2023, 10, 23), 
                   new Date(2023, 9, 10),
                   new Date(2023, 8, 1),
                   new Date(2023, 7, 4),
                   new Date(2023, 7, 7),
                   new Date(2023, 1, 1)]
    findClosestDate(new Date(1995, 10, 3)); // should return dates[3]
```

Comment: The closest of those dates to anything in 1995 is most certainly not `dates[3]`.

Comment: do you mean, the best way to pick the date closest to the user's birthday for a given year, in your case (2023)? Because according to the wording of your question the closest date to the NEXT birthday (2022, 10, 3) would be (2023, 1, 1). From the answer you're expecting it would be better to word it as "the date closest to the user's birthday for a given year"

Comment: Note that `new Date(2023, 12, 23)` creates a *Date* for 23 Jan 2024.

Comment: @TochiBedford—indeed. The first 3 dates in the dates array are for 2024, the rest ore 2023. So how to compare across years? E.g. if the birthday is 1 Dec, then `new Date(2023, 12, 2)` (i.e. 2 Jan 2024) is the closest future date if 2023 is used, or no date if the year of the date in the array is used. If the year is ignored, for a birthday of 3 Nov in 2022, a date for 4 Nov 2030 is "closer" than 5 Nov 2022. :-/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function findClosestDate(date) {
  const today = new Date()
  const nextDate = new Date(date)
  nextDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear())
  if (nextDate < today) {
    nextDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 1)
  }
  console.log(nextDate)
  const dates = [
    new Date(2023, 12, 23),
    new Date(2023, 12, 2),
    new Date(2023, 12, 6),
    new Date(2023, 10, 23),
    new Date(2023, 9, 10),
    new Date(2023, 8, 1),
    new Date(2023, 7, 4),
    new Date(2023, 7, 7),
    new Date(2023, 1, 1)
  ]
  // calculate distance to each date
  const diffs = dates.map(d => Math.abs(nextDate - d))
  // find the lowest
  const best = Math.min(...diffs)
  // get the index of the lowest
  const bestIndex = diffs.indexOf(best)
  // return the best one
  return dates[bestIndex]
}
const result = findClosestDate(new Date(1995, 10, 3));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Sorry, mistake in the post. I would need the date closest to the user's NEXT birthday.

Comment: Hacky but should work

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to have a few uncertainties or mistakes in it, as many of the comments have already pointed out. I am now trying to answer the question in the way that I understood the intention of OP to be: "Which of the proposed dates is the one closest to the given birthday in that *same year*?" Also I assume that OP was not aware that the months counter in `new Date()` is zero based in JavaScript. Therefore I manually adjusted all dates accordingly.

```js
 const dates = [
    new Date(2023, 11, 23),
    new Date(2023, 11, 2),
    new Date(2023, 11, 6),
    new Date(2023, 9, 23),
    new Date(2023, 8, 10),
    new Date(2023, 7, 1),
    new Date(2023, 6, 4),
    new Date(2023, 6, 7),
    new Date(2023, 0, 1)
  ], bd=new Date(1995, 9, 3); // 3 October 1995
// future birthday; 
const fbd=new Date(dates[0].getFullYear(),bd.getMonth(),bd.getDate());

const closest=dates.reduce((a,c)=>Math.abs(c-fbd)<Math.abs(a-fbd)?c:a);

console.log(closest.toLocaleString());
```